# How to optimise for-loop code?

Tags: java, for-loop

How can I optimise this code?

```
List<SemaineTpsRegDto> semaines = ecranDto.getListeSemaine();       
 for (SemaineTpsRegDto semaine : semaines) {
            List<EntiteTpsRegDto> entiteTps = semaine.getListeEntite();
            for (EntiteTpsRegDto entitesTps : entiteTps) {
                List<AgentTpsRegDto> agentTpsReg = entitesTps.getListeAgent();
                for (AgentTpsRegDto agentsTpsReg : agentTpsReg) {
                    List<TempsRegJournalierDto> tempsRegJournalier = agentsTpsReg.getListeTempsJournalier();
                    for (TempsRegJournalierDto tempsRegJour : tempsRegJournalier) {
                        tempsRegJour.getHeureReelle().getDepassement();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is wrong with it? What do you want to optimize?

Comment: What do you mean "optimize"? You can certainly make it more readable in one easy way.

Comment: I wonder if we could make sure we do not have nested FOR

Comment: It seems like you have to go through all of those layers to get to the final sublist so no. If you need to do a 4-level iteration maybe you shouldn't be using lists for something. (Can't tell you what from the code you've supplied, sorry.) In words, what your loop does is *"for every single one in every single one in every single one in every single one"*. If that's what you want then this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline the variables:

```
for (SemaineTpsRegDto semaine : ecranDto.getListeSemaine()) {
  for (EntiteTpsRegDto entitesTps : semaine.getListeEntite()) {
    for (AgentTpsRegDto agentsTpsReg : entitesTps.getListeAgent()) {
      for (TempsRegJournalierDto tempsRegJour : agentsTpsReg.getListeTempsJournalier()) {
        tempsRegJour.getHeureReelle().getDepassement();
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

But this does only improve readability. If you need the variables after the loop it is used in, you can not do this.

Since you have a structure four levels deep, you need four levels of iteration to access every element.

Comment: Exactly. The OP has four layers of lists and wants to do something with every single element so I don't know what they expect to optimize.